# Trying to publish 16 bit images as ROS msg

Tags: ros, cv-bridge, sensor-msgs#image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to publish sensor msg from lepton camera connected over SPI. The images that I get from the sensor is 14 bit, I have zero padded it and have it as 16 bit value. I am trying to publish the 16 bit image as sensor::msgs Image, but the the image message type can hold only 8 bit of data as the data type is `uint8[] data`  (I used the encoding `mono16`). Then I tried with opencv Mat and cv_bridge, the relevant code is

```
cv::Mat image_holder(IR_img.height,IR_img.width, CV_16UC1);
for(int i=(NO_BITS_SKIP+1); i<FRAME_SIZE_UINT16;i++)
        {
            if(i % PACKET_SIZE_UINT16 < 2)
                continue;
            image_holder.at<uchar>(ii,jj)=(unsigned char)init_buf[i];
            jj++;
            if(jj==80)
            {
                jj=0;
                ii++;
            }
            if(ii==60)
            {
                ii=0;
            }
        }
```

where init_buf is a 16bit pointer to the data. When i assign the values into the matrix, its ignoring the 2nd byte and considers only 1st byte. and surprisingly the size of the image is half the size.

This is the 8bit image (successfully published)

[image: image description]

16bit image I am having problems with

[image: image description]

I am not sure where i am going wrong. Is there a tutorial I can refer to for publishing 16 bit grayscale images? Any help is greatly appreciated..

I am using ROS indigo and opencv 2.4.8

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237802/trying-to-publish-16-bit-images-as-ros-msg/) by [SpacemanSPIFF](https://answers.ros.org/users/22434/spacemanspiff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2016-06-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use cv_bridge and make sure to set the encoding to 16-bit

For example

```
cv_bridge::CvImage img16;
// copy raw image into img16.image
img16.encoding = sensor_msgs::image_encodings::MONO16;
// img16.header
image_pub.publish(img16);
```

Just remember to convert it into a 8-bit before displaying it.

```
image_callback(const snesor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& img)
{
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(img, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::MONO16);  
    cv::Mat img8(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CV_8UC1);
    cv_ptr->image.convertTo(img8, CV_8UC1);
    cv::imshow("8-bit Mono", img8);  
    cv::waitKey(1);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [uwleahcim](https://answers.ros.org/users/26636/uwleahcim/) with karma: 101 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SpacemanSPIFF](https://answers.ros.org/users/22434/spacemanspiff/) on 2016-06-27**:
Thanks. Tat was pretty much wat I was trying to do, jus realized tat , the prob was my type cast, as `uchar` ignored the 2nd byte. wen I used `ushort` it solved the issue. I was just curious why we cannot view it as a 16 bit image? wen i `rostopic echo` it displays 8bit values.
-Thank You

**Comment by [pemo](https://answers.ros.org/users/52135/pemo/) on 2020-02-28**:
Great answer. Please be aware of the type of 16 bit to 8 bit conversion you want to accomplish. The above convertTo() only takes into account the first 8 bit and everything above is set to 255. [This OpenCV asnwer](https://answers.opencv.org/question/207313/conversion-16bit-image-to-8-bit-image/?answer=207459#post-id-207459) sums up pretty well the different type of conversions.